# Python & Mac: How to distinguish between folder and package

Tags: python, macos, package, directory, os.path

I'm trying to distinguish between folder and package on a mac using a python code.

os.path.isfile('package') returns false
and os.walk('package') walks trough the package as if it where any ordinary folder.

Thanks for thinking along:)

Comment: You mean [OS X packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_(OS_X)), not Python packages, right? OS X packages are *just folders* with a special package extension in the name.

Comment: What makes a directory a package is configured in the OS somewhere.

Comment: I indeed meant a OS X package. The objects "info window" shows a difference between a folder and a package (Xcode project or an app or whatever..).

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: I just installed the xattr library. However, when I run the xattr.getxattr() function on a file like: xattr.getxattr("fileToBeScanned", u'com.apple.FinderInfo'). I get either nothing for a .DS_Store file, or lots of errors for all other objects (files, folders, packages): IOError: [Errno 93] Attribute not found: